# Uploaded PHP file is not showing in folder

Tags: php

I have a php code that should move an image to a folder but when i navigate to that folder,it doesn't show anything.I'm using Linux as my OS.
How do i make the files to show up on the folder?
Thanks in advance

PHP CODE

```
    <?php 
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $file = $_FILES['file'];
    
            $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
            $fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
            $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
            $fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];
            $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    
            $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName );
            $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));
    
            $allowed = array('jpg','jpeg','png','pdf');
    
            if (in_array($fileActualExt , $allowed)) {
                if ($fileError === 0) {
                    if ($fileSize < 500000) {
                        $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$fileActualExt;
                        $fileDestination = 'uploads/'.$fileNameNew;
                        move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);
                        header("Location: index.php?uploadsuccess");
                    } else {
                        echo "File size is too big";
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "You cannot brain";
                }
            }else {
                echo "You cannot brain";
            }
            
        }    
    ?>
```

INDEX PHP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Files</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file">
        <button type="submit" name="submit">UPLOAD</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

directory structure:
[click to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxqg2.png)

Comment: May you show us your directory structure?

Comment: Make sure the folder is writable by your webserver/PHP

Comment: What's the case of the file extension of the file you are testing? Is it all lower case as your code expects or a different case?

Comment: @kuh-chani i edited my post...there's a link for the directory structure

Comment: @GetSet `$fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));` lowercase?im sorry i just got started php 2 days ago and i don't really know much about this

Comment: My bad, I completely overlooked `strtolower()` already there. A question: What does your `echo()`s report when you comment out the `header()` line? .. Maybe make one of your "You cannot brain" echoes different, so you know where the fault is.

Comment: That is `strtolower()` *should* be there. Thats not the issue since you have it. But what do your `echo()`s report? You may need to comment out the `header()` line to see. I've seen some weird behavior with `header()` being present, at least during testing.

Comment: @GetSet 
I got this error =>
`Warning: move_uploaded_file(uploads/5fd9a53ab57af2.04301274.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Upload files with PHP/upload.php on line 21

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/opt/lampp/temp/phpHUUaBn' to 'uploads/5fd9a53ab57af2.04301274.png' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Upload files with PHP/upload.php on line 21`

Comment: Ok. If a "failed to open" error, might have to change your "chmod" permissions as per @brombeer in that comment above. I use Windows so I cant really help you further, by experience anyway. .... But it appears that your `Upload` folder itself doesnt have "write" enabled on "chmod" permissions. Worth checking out.

Comment: alright thanks for the help, i really appreciate it

Comment: Looks like the file is being uploaded. But just cant be moved. I'm noticing a `uploads/` in the Warning. This is different from the successful temp path upload. So the permissions have to do with the path to move it to. ....... Check if `$fileDestination` exists and has correct permissions. You appear to define it as "relative".

Answer (score 1):

your code is correct
but you haven't permission to write a file to the directory
you need to change directory permission

```
sudo chmod -R 777 directoryName
```

the above command change directory permission to read write and execute
in Linux you can change file permission with chmod command
you can give specific permission to your directory as your need

to see the error of your page
comment the header like this

```
//header("Location: index.php?uploadsuccess");
```

and use `exit();`
then you can see what is the exact error you page generating

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to upload a file

```
<?php 
 // File upload path
    $targetDir = "uploads/";
    $fileName = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;
    $fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_FILES["file"]["name"])){
// Allow certain file formats
$allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif','pdf');
if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){
    // Upload file to server
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $targetFilePath)){
        // Insert image file name into database
        $insert = $db->query("INSERT into images (file_name, uploaded_on) VALUES ('".$fileName."', NOW())");
        if($insert){
            $statusMsg = "The file ".$fileName. " has been uploaded successfully.";
        }else{
            $statusMsg = "File upload failed, please try again.";
        } 
    }else{
        $statusMsg = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}else{
    $statusMsg = 'Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG, GIF, & PDF files are allowed to upload.';
}
 }else{
$statusMsg = 'Please select a file to upload.';
}
 echo $statusMsg;
 ?>
```

Comment: `move_uploaded_file()` can move to relative path tho correct?